# how to copy whole rows (absolute references)

Tags: excel, vba

I have to make a Macro that copies, whole rows of a an Excel Sheet (incluiding absolute references or formulas), and pastes them in the lower part acording to a comparison. By this i mean that i have to copy not only the content of a cell, but also the absolute reference or formula, so if a cell is modified the change will be reflected on the part where i had copied the cell. The rows will be copied acording to an comparasion made between a text in a string and on the cells of the row that is going to be copied. The tricky part so far it has been how to copy the absolute reference or formula

Here is the code i have so far...

```
 Sub Foo()
    Dim i As Long, iMatches As Long
    Dim aTokens() As String
    aTokens = Split("DCV-", ",")
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("I1:I104")
       If (Len(cell.Value) <> 0) Then
          For i = 0 To UBound(aTokens)
             If InStr(1, cell.Value, aTokens(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                iMatches = (iMatches + 1)
                ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row).Copy ActiveSheet.Rows(iMatches + 105)
                'Sheets("DP_PA 9.70 REV").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Sheets("DP_PA 9.70 REV").Rows(iMatches + 105)
             End If
          Next
       End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? Or the wrong result?

Comment: No, i dont get an error, the thing is that im triying to copy the rows that complies with the condition i define, but im not triying to copy just the data of the cell, instead im triying to copy the cell reference, so if a changed is made in the origin cell, it will be reflected on the copied cell.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you describe the steps you would manually do to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an exact copy of a formula (or formulas) that preserves all the cell references, you can use something like:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range("A20:B21").Formula = Range("A1:B2").Formula
End With
```

Comment: Ok so how can i use the .Formula to copy the rows that comply with the condition ive established? Specifically this line is the one i wanna modified, to make it copy the formula or reference                                                          ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row).Copy

Comment: As the example shows, the destination range (in this case, the formulas in the destination row is set equal to the formulas in the source row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a reference to the data, all you need to do is to create a formula that refers to that cell.

Try with something like this:

```
FirstPartOfFormula = "='" & Sheet1.Name & "'!"
For C = 1 to 3
  Sheet2.Cells(R2, C).Formula = FirstPartOfFormula & Sheet1.Cells(R1, C).Address
Next C
```